# asp.NET - Custom Error Messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I have this code in my web.config file:

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="~/GeneralError.aspx" mode="On">
  <error statusCode="401" redirect="401.aspx" />
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

This works perfectly on my local machine while running IIS and it redirects to my error pages, however when I run it on the server, IIS's default error pages pop in instead of mine.

Why is this? How can I fix this? Is this something related from the code, or is this some setting on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the right solution for your issue, but double check IIS settings (Error Pages)

http://blogs.iis.net/rakkimk/archive/2008/10/03/iis7-enabling-custom-error-pages.aspx

IIS error pages settings override application config.

Answer (score 0):

This format was working for me

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="~/GeneralError.aspx" mode="On">
     <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/GeneralError.aspx" />
     <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/GeneralError.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

or

```
<error statusCode="404" redirect="filenotfound.htm" />
```